# Show vertical lines between columns

Tags: text, scribus

I have a text frame with several columns and I would like to add vertical lines between them. Is there some automatic way how to do that, or I have to do it manually?

**I have this:**
[image: columns without line]

**I want this:**
[image: columns with line]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no. You have to draw the lines.

You can use the "align and distribute" dialog to place them in the middle.

And holding down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button while drawing a line helps you creating a vertical line.

On the other side, those lines mostly do not look that nice... (your screenshot is probably only a sample, but it shows well what could go wrong) and there are often better ways for making pretty columns.

Comment: Is there some way how to use "Align and Distribute" dialog if I have three columns?

Comment: Yes: draw one of the vertical lines, duplicate / copy paste it three times; use "align and distribute" to align one line to the left and one to the right of the area (you can vertically align or use the <kbd>shift</kdb> (thanks @lucian)  key to only move horizontally); equally distribute the four lines; delete the lines at the left and the right. You are left with two lines that are correctly placed... but is it worth the hassle? : - )

Comment: Thanks, I understand you, but I have to mimic some old newspapers which had these lines between columns, so I can't choose the easy way. ;-)